# How to sync local and remote Django databases

Tags: database, git, heroku

I created a Django website and filled the database with some entries. I then uploaded the site to Heroku. Later, I added more entries, but I mistakenly added them to the remote database.

I would like to (1) sync the local and remote databases (so that all the new material I added to the remote database gets copied to the local database) and (2) from now on work in such a way that I add entries to the local database first and then those entries get added to the remote database when I git push.

Any idea how to do this? Thank you.